# SharePoint Online List - Sort by Multi select People Column

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, people-picker, sorting, multi-select

I have a requirement to sort a SharePoint Online list by a people column called "Owner".  The issue is that this is a multi-select people field.  Does anyone have a suggestion for how I can accomplish this?  My initial thought was to Create a text column called "Owner Name", and have Power Automate push those values' Display Names to the text column.  The flow keeps giving me an error "the result of the evaluation of 'foreach' expression '@items('Apply_to_each') is type of 'Object'.  The result must be a valid array".  My flow's set up is:

- Manually Trigger a flow
- Get Items
- Initialize Variable - Name: varMultipleOwners - Type: String
- Append to String Variable - varMultipleOwners;
- Apply to Each - Update Item - "Owner Name" - varMultipleOwners

Any help would be great.

Thank you